# Sharing static files from a directory that shares a name with controller

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2, kohana, kohana-3

I'm using kohana 3 for a project and have a controller /foo with various actions (/foo/about, /foo/features, et cetera). However, I was just recently given a couple folders with a fairly large html site to be placed within this directory including html/txt/picture files. I now have a structure that looks like this

- kohana/foo/help/index.html
- kohana/foo/help_de/index.html
- kohana/foo/help_es/index.html

and so on..

My application serves these files just perfectly, however, when I go to the /foo controller - it no longer works. I can solve this problem by editing my htaccess file to be as such:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system|foo)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]
```

However, then, my static files don't get served. What can I do to serve the static files if they exist but default back to my controller/actions when they don't?

I've been trying to edit the htaccess to only serve files from the list of folders but cannot figure out the proper way to go about doing this.

Please let me know if I must be more descriptive.

Thank you -

Edit (full .htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/foo` link is being broken by this line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Because `/foo` is being seen as a directory. You could probably just remove that line, as long as you aren't worried about losing directory indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know kohana, but I imagine it can work if you add in your .htacess after "RewriteEngine on" 2 lines:

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f #Exlude files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d #Exlude directories

This will exclude files and directories from beign processed.

Comment: ah, yes - I do have that already. I suppose I should have entered the full file in the original post